# Simple Clock in Meteor.js or how to reload Templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, refresh, clock

I'm trying with Templates in meteor.js, but how can I reload them after a given time? For example I want to have a Template called "time" which has to reload every second to show the current time, also a template "date" which has to reload every minute, because every minute the date can change, or an calendar which has to reload the .ics every 5 minute or so, to be always accurate.

my current code looks like that:

```
<body>
    <!-- TOP -->
    <div class="top left">{{> time }}</div>
    <div class="top mid"></div>
    <div class="top right">{{> date }}</div> 
    
</body>

<template name="time">
<div>{{ clock }}</div>
</template>

<template name="date">
<div>{{ date }}</div> 
</template>
```

the js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    
    Template.time.helpers({
        clock: function () {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
            currentHours = ( currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentHours;
            currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
            currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;
            return currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;
        }
        
    });
    
    Tempate.date.helpers({
        date: function () {
            var month = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Dezember"];
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            return d + " " + month[m] + " " + y;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You might find the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to reload a template is to provide and change a reactive data source. In your case, this could be the clock value.

```
var clock = new ReactiveVar(new Date());

Template.time.onCreated(function() {
  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    clock.set(new Date());
  }, 1000);
});

Template.time.helpers({
  clock: function() {
    var currentTime = clock.get();
    ... 
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know how to interval and this onCreate!