# FlowRouter - force a template to re-render

Tags: meteor, flow-router

In a Meteor app, I have the structure:

```
<main template>

  <side menu></side menu>

  <delegate to different content template/>

</main template>
```

In the side menu I put helper functions to change words/icons/etc based on routes. (clicking links in the different templates changes the current route)

How do I force those helpers to run on route change? It seems like I cannot...

Comment: I've found a 'hacky' fix, where i change a session variable. then by accessing the session variable the side menu becomes reactive.... This is not good i think

Comment: Use reactive values like `FlowRouter.getRouteName()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Clock in Meteor.js or how to reload Templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626845/simple-clock-in-meteor-js-or-how-to-reload-templates)